# How to write a Qt application that uses Kvantum blur

Tags: node.js, linux, qt, qt5

I'm trying to build an application (with [nodegui](https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui)) that uses the blur effect that is applied via [Kvantum](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/tree/master/Kvantum).
If this is not possible with `node.js`, I'm fine to use any other language (*would be nice if it just work with VS Code instead of QT Creator*)

Currently I'm using [PlasmaSur-dark](https://store.kde.org/p/1406032/) and apps like Dolphin works fine.
But when I write a simple Qt app like

```js
import { QMainWindow } from "@nodegui/nodegui";

const win = new QMainWindow();
win.setWindowTitle("pacman UI");
win.resize(800, 600);

win.show();

(global as any).win = win;
```

it doesn't apply the blur configured in Kvantum like for Dolphin :/

I used this as a base: https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui-starter

[image: screenshot]